# php populate data not getting transfered with form

Tags: php

i m working on a php page 
data is getting retrieved from database and everything is working fine
except that the retrieved data is not getting passed along the form but all others does. only the data i select in the sql drop down box is not saving.

```
<html>
<head>  
<?php
include('connection.php');
$options = '';
$filter=mysql_query("select distinct username from user");
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($filter)) {
$options .="<option value=".$row['username'].">" . $row['username'] .     "</option>";
}

$menu="<form>
<select>
  " . $options . "
</select>
 </form>";
 ? >


 <title>Bug Report</title>
</head>
<body>
<form  action="bugprocess.php" method="get">
<table width="274" border="0" align="center" cellpadding="2" cellspacing="0">
<tr>
<td width="95"><div align="right">name:</div></td>
<td width="171"><input type="text" name="name" /></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><div align="right">description:</div></td>
<td><input type="text" name="description" /></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><div align="right">priority:</div></td>
<td><select name="priority"><option value="high">high</option>
<option value="low">low</option>
<option value="medium">medium</option>
</select></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><div align="right">assign:</div> </td> <td><name="assign"><?php echo $menu?></td>

<td><div align="right"></div></td>
</table>
<br /><center><input name="submit" type="submit" value="Submit" /></td>

</form>
```

thank you

Comment: if you open source code in the browser, can you see your values for dropdown menu? You might want to use single quotes to wrap your value in `<option value='".$row['username']."'>`

Comment: You should set a name for your select in `$menu`, otherwise it will not be sent.

Comment: i tried both naming and setting option value='" but if i set select name page wont display and if i set the option value like above it doesnt display data

Answer (score 1):

your select does not have a "name" attribute , also remove additional form tag from $menu. I have corrected the code for you(shown below). the name of select input is "assign"

```
    $menu="
    <select name="assign">
      " . $options . "
    </select>";
```

Comment: you have an error in your closing `?>` tag after the `$menu` - there's an extra space

Comment: when having blank screen use `error_reporting()` and `display_errors()` to check what errors is PHP throwing out

Answer (score 0):

Ok, you got 2 bugs in your code, one is that you have not set name for the `select` input, the other is that you got tag `<form>` set twice. This won't work.

Try to change this:

```
$menu="<form>
<select>
  " . $options . "
</select>
 </form>";
```

into this:

```
$menu = "<select name='assign'>".$options."</select>";
```